# GNU make yields "commands commence before first target" error

Tags: makefile, gnu

In my makefile, I would like to check for the existence of a library and give an informative error message. I created a conditional that should exit the make process when the file is not found:

```
 9: ifeq ($(${JSONLIBPATH}),)
10:    JSONLIBPATH = ${ALTJSONLIBDIR}/${LIBJSON}
11: endif
12: ifeq ($(${JSONLIBPATH}),)
13:    $(error JSON library is not found. Please install libjson before building)
14: endif
```

My makefile gets stuck on line 13:

```
Makefile:13: *** commands commence before first target.  Stop.
```

After line 13, my makefile has its targets.

I tried putting this conditional block into a target (e.g. a target called `isJSONLibraryInstalled`) but this does not execute correctly.

How would I check for a file's existence and handle the error case, before processing targets? Apologies if this is a dumb question.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

First of all, you are looking at the contents of a variable that is named after the current path, which is probably not what you want. A simple environment variable reference is `$(name)` or `${name}`, not `$(${name})`. Due to this, line 13 is always evaluated.

Second, I think it is choking on the indentation of the `$(error ...)` expression. While the expression resolves to an empty string, there is still a tab character at the start of the line, which indicates a command, which in turn cannot exist outside a rule.

I think using spaces rather than tabs to indent would work.

Comment: Richer : I was stuck with this for long where I used tabs instead of spaces and got `*** commands commence before first target` error. You saved the day. Many Thanks... :)

Comment: Great observation .. tab in the forbidden place :)

Comment: I am getting `missing separator.  Stop.` Any potential reason?

Comment: if you get missing operator you are probably using space instead of tabs

Answer (score 8):

When you get Make error messages, always check the [Error message documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Error-Messages)

On GNU Make 3.81 (`error` appears to have been removed from newer versions), it says:

> This means the first thing in the makefile seems to be part of a command script: it begins with a TAB character and doesn't appear to be a legal make command (such as a variable assignment). Command scripts must always be associated with a target.

What makes matters more confusing is that "doesn't appear to be a legal make command" part. That explains why in:

```
    a := b
    $(error a)
```

the error happens at line 2 and not 1: `make` simply accepts statements that it can parse, like the assignment, so the following works:

```
    a := b
a:
    echo $a
```

Note: [SO currently converts tabs to spaces in code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143632/tabs-converted-to-spaces), so you can't just copy the above code into your editor.

Comment: The `error` function still works with GNU Make 4.2.1

Answer (score 1):

For me it was an unnecessary white space before the connector that was causing this.
On slickEdit I selected the option to view all special character and noticed the black sheep.

Comment: Close, it's the unnecessary tab character before `$(error ...` substitution that's causing the error. Deleting it or replacing it with spaces would make the error go away.

Answer (score 1):

You can check **whitespaces**, **spaces** and **tabs** by using **VSCode** [View **>** Render Whitespace]

As you can see;

- **command-1** has a **tab** (->) and **whitespace** at the end
- **command-2** has **space** at first
- **command-3/4** has **tab**+**spaces**

[image]

So, you should remove the **whitespaces** at the end and apply the same spaces with the same action. e.g: **tab** like the following;

[image]