# makefile: commands commence before first target

Tags: makefile

I have a rule like below just for test

```
test:
ifeq (1,1)
$(info --)
endif
    echo kkk
```

when I run `make test`, it shows

> makefile:41: *** commands commence before first target.  Stop.

What is wrong?

**edit**

according to Florian Weimer, we should indent the `$(info --)` line. But If I write

```
test:
ifeq (1,1)
    $(info --)
endif
    echo kkk

test2:
ifeq (1,1)
$(info --)
endif
    echo kkk
```

then `make test` will complain that

> makefile:11: *** commands commence before first target.  Stop.

So doesn't make always scan the whole makefile? It seems that it doesn't stop after rule test is finished

Comment: Does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713663/gnu-make-yields-commands-commence-before-first-target-error

Comment: @jwdonahue Yeah, I saw this link. But I still don't know why my rule is wrong

Comment: Indentation perhaps?

Comment: @jwdonahue I know the difference between space and tab. so I differentiate them. But why `echo kkk` is not right? it is indented by a tab, and interpreted by shell

Answer (score 2):

You need to tab-indent the `$(info --)` line, so that it does not terminate the recipe, like this:

```
test:
ifeq (1,1)
    $(info --)
endif
    echo kkk
```

(Obviously, you need to use tabs here.)

**EDIT** The make documentation of conditional blocks consistently uses tab indentation within recipes, and spaces or no indentation outside of recipes.  This is why there are both styles.

The full example works for me if I indent both `$(info --)` lines.

Comment: Hi, Florian Weimer. If I indent the $(info ) line. then make complains errors that after the test rule. This makes me confused, why make doesn't stop after test rule? Does make always scan the whole makefile?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a minimal example which shows the problem, along with the error message.

Comment: Hi, @Florian Weimer. Thank you very much. I made a edit. But I still confused. Because people say, lines begin with tab is shell. Why I should indent `$(info ---)` between ifeq

Comment: and according to the doc https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_7.html   there are several examples have no indent