# Error while trying to get value from command in gnu make

Tags: linux, shell, makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I’ve the following code which run on make gnu file

```
apps := $(shell tbd run apps)
apps := $(subst ],,$(subst [,,$(app)))
```

Now I want to print the app value and I tried with

```
@echo $(app)
```

And I got error

`Makefile:12: *** commands commence before first target.  Stop.`

**update:**

currently my code is like

```
apps := $(shell tbd run apps)
apps := $(subst ],,$(subst [,,$(apps)))


build:
    @for app in $(apps) ; do \
     bsd start $$app ; \
    done
```

And if I try it like this I got error

```
start: 
   apps := $(shell tbd run apps)
   apps := $(subst ],,$(subst [,,$(apps)))

build:
    @for app in $(apps) ; do \
        bsd start $$app ; \
    done
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GNU make yields "commands commence before first target" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713663/gnu-make-yields-commands-commence-before-first-target-error)

Comment: @tripleee - not the same, I try with `$app` (as in the post answer) without success same error, any idea?

Comment: Not the accepted answer; the other one.

Comment: @tripleee - try it now also , I dont get erorr but still I dont see the value

Comment: @tripleee - done I've update but the problem is when I put it in recipe I got anohter error, lets put it like this if I want to user the app value inside other recipe how should I do it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181881/discussion-between-rayn-d-and-tripleee).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot meaningfully put a Makefile function call inside of a shell invocation.  I guess you are really just looking for

```
build:
    tbd run apps \
    | sed 's/\[//;s/\]//' \
    | xargs -n 1 bsd start
```

Comment: Thanks : ) what I need is getting list of apps and running in loop on them and this works, except I want print the values

Comment: sorry I dont understand how this should work can you provide the complite code ? does this replace all the code in my update ?

Comment: 1+ for your help :)

Comment: This is a complete Makefile to replace the code you have in your question, yes.

Comment: Sorry, what is `bsd start` ? can it be simplified ?

Comment: I have simply refactored the code you posted. I have no idea what the commands `tbd run` and `bsd start` from your question actually do.

Comment: Sorry for asking this , but is there is option to make the code In my last update to print the value to the screen ?

Comment: I replied to that earlier. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52815860/error-while-trying-to-get-value-from-command-in-gnu-make/52816615?noredirect=1#comment92550585_52816615

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181883/discussion-between-rayn-d-and-tripleee).

Comment: Can we please chat shortly ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print something regardless of any rule then use the [info](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Make-Control-Functions) function...

```
$(info $(app))
```

Comment: btw I dont see the error but I dont see the value either what do you think is still can be missing?

Comment: That suggests the output of `$(shell tbd run apps)` is an empty string.

Comment: No it isnt :) should I check it mabye like this `@echo $(info $(app))`

Comment: How do you know it isn't empty?  Try putting `$(info app='$(app)')` on a line immediately after `app := $(shell tbd run apps)` in your makefile.  Do you see any output?

Comment: No, you cannot run a shell command in the middle of your `Makefile`, it needs to be part of a recipe; that's what the error message means and that's what the nominated duplicate is telling you.